# List in Python avoid only the first negative element

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to compare numbers from a numbers.txt file. Whats bothering me is the negative index property in Python, where negative number actually means reading from right to left.

Is there a way to ignore just the first comparison? Where I output that there is no previous number(see desired output)

Important is that I can not change my numbers.txt file. These I get automatically generated from another function.

```
$ cat numbers.txt

1
2
3
4
5
```

code:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    print lines
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        previous_number = lines[i-1]
        current_number = lines[i]
        print "current Nr: ", current_number
        print "previous Nr: ", previous_number
        if current_number > previous_number:
            print " current Nr is larger"
        else:
            print "current Nr is smaller"
```

output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
current Nr:  1
previous Nr:  5
current Nr is  smaller
current Nr:  2
previous Nr:  1
 current Nr is larger
current Nr:  3
previous Nr:  2
 current Nr is larger
current Nr:  4
previous Nr:  3
 current Nr is larger
current Nr:  5
previous Nr:  4
 current Nr is larger
```

desired output

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
current Nr:  1
previous Nr:  There is no previous!
current Nr is  none
current Nr:  2
previous Nr:  1
 current Nr is larger
current Nr:  3
previous Nr:  2
 current Nr is larger
current Nr:  4
previous Nr:  3
 current Nr is larger
current Nr:  5
previous Nr:  4
 current Nr is larger
```

Comment: Let me please state here, that your question doesn't have anything to do with python's indexing, as you do not even try to implement the case where you want to print "There is no previous!". If python would not provide negative indices, your program would throw an error. So my advice: forget about the -1 index and think about what you have to add to your loop to catch the first case which is different from the others...

Comment: What are you *acually* trying to accomplish? Do you really need exactly that output, or do you want to iterate over the list in adjacent pairs?

Comment: That said, additionally two hints: lines = file.read().splitlines() can be shorter lines = file.readlines() and as already mentioned in sn answer below,  enumerate is the command of choice if you want to write for i in range(len(lines)):

Comment: @SpghttCd I did try implementing an exception but that didnt work as expected. I know that would throw an error thats why I opened this in the first place. See my response to DeepSpace

Comment: I think I understand - you expected an exception which you wanted to catch, but python knows index -1, therefore no exception... In the end you simply should add an if-structure which checks, if you're in the first iteration of your loop, ie i==0. If yes, write your string, if no, write lines[i-1].

Comment: @SpghttCd yes the condition does work as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to check on index

```
for i, value in enumerate(lines):
  previous_number = "None"
  CurrentNrText = "None"
  if i != 0:
    previous_number = lines[i-1]
    if current_number > previous_number:
       CurrentNrText = " current Nr is larger"
     else:
       CurrentNrText = "current Nr is smaller"

  current_number = lines[i]
  print("current Nr: ", current_number)
  print("previous Nr: ", previous_number)
  print(CurrentNrText)
```

Comment: That works as well but ignores the first element as current Nr.
I would rather get the current Nr. as 1 and detect that there are no number before it...

Comment: I have edited code for more details. you just had to edit the code based on condition. anyways Its done in the edit now

Comment: great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start from the second number, then explicitly start from the second number:

```
for i in range(1, len(lines)):
```

Or, even better, use the more idiomatic `enumerate`:

```
for i, number in enumerate(lines[1:], 1):
```

Comment: That works but not exactly. In this case I simply ignore the first elemt as current Nr.
I would rather get the current Nr. as 1 and detect that there are no number before it. That first element being spotted as a current Nr is important.

Comment: @Lango So simply add an if condition that checks if `i == 0` to your current code. I don't see where the issue is

Comment: thank you. It does work when adding an if condition-

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try this method :

```
with open('numbers.txt') as file:
    numbers=[None,]
    for line in file:
        numbers.append(line)
    for idx,no in enumerate(numbers,1):
        try:

            if numbers[idx]>numbers[idx-1]:
                print('Current no is {}'.format(numbers[idx]))
                print('Previous no is {}'.format(numbers[idx-1]))
                print ("current Nr is larger")
            else:
                print ("current Nr is smaller")
        except TypeError:
            print('Current no is {}'.format(numbers[idx]))
            print('There is no previous!')
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

output:

```
Current no is 1

There is no previous!
Current no is 2

Previous no is 1

current Nr is larger
Current no is 3

Previous no is 2

current Nr is larger
Current no is 4

Previous no is 3

current Nr is larger
Current no is 5
Previous no is 4

current Nr is larger
```